# Python's Multiple Inheritance: Picking which super() to call

Tags: python, multiple-inheritance, super

In Python, how do I pick which Parent's method to call? Say I want to call the parent ASDF2's `__init__` method. Seems like I have to specify **ASDF1** in the super()..? And if I want to call ASDF3's `__init__`, then I must specify **ASDF2**?!

```py
>>> class ASDF(ASDF1, ASDF2, ASDF3):
...     def __init__(self):
...         super(ASDF1, self).__init__()
            
>>> ASDF()
# ASDF2's __init__ happened

>>> class ASDF(ASDF1, ASDF2, ASDF3):
...     def __init__(self):
...         super(ASDF2, self).__init__()

>>> ASDF()
# ASDF3's __init__ happened
```

Seems bonkers to me. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 95, accepted):

That's not what [`super()`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#super) is for. Super basically picks one (or all) of its parents in a specific order. If you only want to call a single parent's method, do this

```
class ASDF(ASDF1, ASDF2, ASDF3):
    def __init__(self):
        ASDF2.__init__(self)
```

Comment: Unfortunately if __init__ references any private methods this wont' work.

Comment: @ErikAronesty The concept of private methods doesn't exist in Python, can you clarify what you mean?

Comment: @nearoo yes, if a method starts with "\_\_" its method name is mangled and the *method is private*.   the \_\_init\_\_ function, when called this way, will not work with private methods.   super() will.

Comment: What's the point of inheriting then? You don't need to inherit to access `ASDF2` in this case. It is a global definition.

Comment: Why you said it picks `(or all)`? Doesn't it always pick the first one?

Answer (score 12):

`super` calls the next method in the method resolution order. In a linear inheritance tree, that will be method from the immediately parent class.

Here, you have three parents, and the next `__init__` method from `ASDF1`'s perspective is that of `ASDF2`. In general, the safe thing to do is to pass the first class in the inheritance list to `super` unless you know why you want to do something else.

The point of all of this is to relieve you of having to explicitly pick which `__init__` methods to call. The question here is why you don't want to call all of the superclass `__init__` methods.

There's a fairly substantial literature on the use of `super` in python, and I recommend that you google the topic, and read what results.

Comment: If I have a class that inherits from `threading.Thread` and `ASDF2` then, when I call `super().__init__()` the thread will not be initialized and will throw an exception: `RuntimeError: thread.__init__() not called`

Answer (score 10):

You are passing ASDF1 (one of your parent classes) as the first argument to super().  Don't do that. Instead, you should pass ASDF as the first argument to super().

[Python 2.7 documentation for super()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#super)

To quote the Python 2.7 docs, a typical superclass call looks like this:

```
class C(B):
    def method(self, arg):
        super(C, self).method(arg)
```

Notice that the first argument to super here is C, which is the current class. Don't pass B (the parent class) to super().

When determining the Method Resolution Order (MRO) super skips the class that is passed in as its first argument, and starts looking at that class' parents and siblings. So, when you passed ASDF1 as the first argument to super(), it skipped over ASDF1 and started its search with ASDF2. That's why ASDF2's `__init__` was called.

---

In Python 3, you don't have to pass the current class any more.

```
class C(B):
    def method(self, arg):
        super().method(arg)    # This does the same thing as:
                               # super(C, self).method(arg)
                               # (Python 3 only)
```

Answer (score 0):

Now in python3, just control which method super() is searching in mro.

```
class _TestA:
    def __init__(self, foo: str):
        self._print = "testA-" + foo


class _TestB:
    def __init__(self, foo: str):
        self._print = "testB-" + foo


class TestAB(_TestA, _TestB):
    def __init__(self, foo: str):
        self._foo = foo
        if foo == "A":
            self._runA()
        else:
            self._runB()
        print(self._print)

    def _runA(self):
        print("Running _TestA")
        super().__init__(self._foo)

    def _runB(self):
        print("Running _TestB")
        super(_TestA, self).__init__(self._foo)


ta = TestAB("A") 
tb = TestAB("B")
```

This gives

```
Running _TestA
testA-A
Running _TestB
testB-B
```