# How to invoke __repr__ of parent class?

Tags: python

So the situation I want to resolve is pretty simple. Say I have a subclass `C` that extends parents `B` and `A`. Parents `B`, and `A` each have their own `__repr__` methods. When I print `C`, the `__repr__` method of parent `A` is always invoked, but I want to invoke parent `B`'s.

How can I do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python's Multiple Inheritance: Picking which super() to call](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14206015/pythons-multiple-inheritance-picking-which-super-to-call)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assume `A` is defined like this:

```
class A():
    def __repr__(self):
        return "This is A"
```

and `B` is defined similarly:

```
class B():
    def __repr__(self):
        return "This is B"
```

while `C` is defined like so:

```
class C(A, B):
    def __init__(self):
        pass
```

or something similar. `print(A())` will yield `This is A`, while the same for `B()` will yield `This is B`. `print(C())` will, as you describe, give `This is A`. However, if you just change the order of `C`'s inheritance:

```
class C(B, A): # change order of A and B
    def __init__(self):
        pass
```

then `print(C())` will give you `This is B`. Simple as that.

Answer (score 1):

If all I wanted was to call an inherited class's repr I would just do:

```
class C(B, A): # whatever order
    def __repr__(self):
        return A.__repr__(self)
```

I had a case similar, but slightly different to this question. I wanted to print the default repr of an inherited class. For me class `C` was dynamically defined with `B` being a mixin class, but I wanted to show the name and module of the "main" class A. I ended up with this solution.

```
class C(B, A):
    def __repr__(self):
        '''Override repr to show the name and path of the main cls.'''
        return '<{} {}.{} object at {}>'.format(
            self.__class__.__name__,
            A.__module__,
            A.__name__,
            hex(id(self)))
```