# python problems with super

Tags: python-2.7, pyside, maya, super

Ok so I'm having a bit of a problem with the code below.  It works as is but if I try to change the part with the comment about me not being able to get super to work correctly to.

```
pipeline_class_call = super(Error_Popup,self)
broken_file_w_whats_wrong = pipeline_class_call.whats_wrong_with_file()
```

or to

```
 broken_file_w_whats_wrong = super(Error_Popup,self).whats_wrong_with_file()
```

and change

```
class Error_Popup(QtGui.QDialog):
```

to

```
class Error_Popup(QtGui.QDialog,Pipeline_UI):
```

I get the following error

```
# TypeError: object of type 'instancemethod' has no len() #
```

Which normally means that I need to call the method, but doesn't super handle all this for me.  Or am I goofing this?

```
from PySide import QtCore, QtGui
from shiboken import wrapInstance
import pymel.core as pm
import maya.OpenMayaUI as omui
from UI.UI import Pipeline_UI

def something_bad_happened_window():
    sbh_pointer = omui.MQtUtil.mainWindow()
    return wrapInstance(long(sbh_pointer), QtGui.QWidget)

class Error_Popup(QtGui.QDialog):

    def __init__(self,parent=something_bad_happened_window()):
        super(Error_Popup,self).__init__(parent)

        self.setWindowTitle('Something Bad Happened!')
        self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.Tool)
        self.popup_layout()
        self.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_DeleteOnClose)
        self.connections()

    def popup_layout(self):
        self.file_description = QtGui.QListWidget()


        #cant seem to get super to work appropriately... booo
        pipeline_class_call = Pipeline_UI()
        broken_file_w_whats_wrong = pipeline_class_call.whats_wrong_with_file()

        for display in range(0,len(broken_file_w_whats_wrong)):

            broken_list = QtGui.QListWidgetItem()
            if display % 2 == 0:
                broken_list.setText(broken_file_w_whats_wrong[display][0])
                broken_list.asset = broken_file_w_whats_wrong[display][1]

            else:
                broken_list.setText("   " + broken_file_w_whats_wrong[display][0])

            self.file_description.addItem(broken_file_w_whats_wrong[display])

        self.import_button = QtGui.QPushButton('Import Replacement(s)')

        error_layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        error_layout.setContentsMargins(2,2,2,2)
        error_layout.setSpacing(2)


        error_layout.addWidget(self.file_description)
        error_layout.addWidget(self.import_button)

        error_layout.addStretch()


        self.setLayout(error_layout)

    def connections(self):
        self.import_button.clicked.connect(Error_Popup.make_sphere)


    @classmethod
    def make_sphere(cls):
        pm.polySphere()


def show_window():

    ui = Error_Popup()

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        try:
            ui.close()
        except:
            pass

    ui.show()

show_window()
```

Thanks in advance everyone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks to me like it's a problem of using `super` with multiple inheritance. It picks one of the parents in a certain order to use.  For example, `super(Error_Popup,self).__init__(parent)` only calls one of the parents `__init__` methods.  You have to manually call all of them.

When calling methods or accessing variables, you have to be specific about which parent you want to use or `super` will pick for you.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14206015/pythons-multiple-inheritance-picking-which-super-to-call) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277367/how-does-pythons-super-work-with-multiple-inheritance).

Comment: makes me question the validity of super in general.

Comment: I think Super is a great design in itself. But it can be confusing on how it works. In general multiple inheritance is complex and you should be aware how the MRO works. I think this explains super the best https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EiOglTERPEo