# Pythonic Approach to Multiple Parent Method Calls

Tags: python, multiple-inheritance

Suppose I have the following class structure:

```
class Mixin1(Base1):
    def get_data(self):
        # Gather some data in some way


class Mixin2(Base2):
    def get_data(self):
        # Gather some data in another way


class MyClass(Mixin1, Mixin2):
    def get_data(self):
        # Gather some data in yet another way.  Then...
        # Get Mixin2's version of get_data.  Then...
        # Get Mixin1's version of get_data.
```

An example case to provide some context is that `Mixin1` is an authentication handler and `Mixin2` is a login handler.  The functionality in the parent classes will populate instance variables (say, error messages).

What would be the most Pythonic approach to calling the parent's `get_data` methods?

One approach to get this kind of information might be something like this:

```
original_class = self.__class__.__base__
parents = [base for base in original_class.__bases__]
for parent in parents:
    parent.get_data()
```

I don't see this as an unreasonable approach but if I have to start crawling into the meta I begin to wonder if there is a more Pythonic approach.

Any suggestions?  Is it possible to use `super()` for this?

Comment: `super()` is precisely what you should be using, as it is intended to solve exactly this problem.

Comment: You should read [Super considered super](https://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/) which explains exactly how to use super in a multiple inheritance scenario.

Comment: @kindall How do you handle the case of choosing which parent's method to call using `super()`? What if you want to call them in a particular order?

Comment: If I read "Super considered super" properly, it would only call one super and mask the others. Rico wants to call both supers.

Comment: @cpburnz: It follows the [C3 linearization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C3_linearization).  In brief, you list the class you want called into first as your first superclass.

Comment: From the documentation: "The second use case is to support cooperative multiple inheritance". Cooperative means all the classes in the class hierarchy are designed to work together. If `super` isn't called from all of them, they aren't designed properly.

Comment: The parent classes in this case do not inherit from anything and do not `super`.  So, "Super considered super" did not address my question.  I've read that many times - fantastic read!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
class MyClass(Mixin1, Mixin2):
    def get_data(self):
        # do local stuff
        data2 = Mixin2.get_data(self)
        data1 = Mixin1.get_data(self)
```

Also, [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14206015/pythons-multiple-inheritance-picking-which-super-to-call) seems to be related.

Another approach is to use containment instead of inheritance.