# Python multi inheritance super keyword

Tags: python, python-3.x

Why?

What I want to show is:

```
====User Data====
User Name : Tom
User Age : 22
User Address : shanghai
```

Tips:It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.
So,

```py
class A:
    def __init__(self, userName=''):
        self.userName = userName
    def showInfo(self):
        print(f'User Name：{self.userName}')


class B:
    def __init__(self, userAge=0):
        self.userAge = userAge
    def showInfo(self):
        print(f'User Age：{self.userAge}')


class C(A, B):
    def __init__(self, userName='', userAge=0, userAddress=''):
        super(C, self).__init__(userName)
        super(C, self).__init__(userAge)
        self.userAddress = userAddress

    def showInfo(self):
        print('====User Data====')
        super(C, self).showInfo()
        super(C, self).showInfo()
        print(f'User Address：{self.userAddress}')

# why User Name 22 ?
# ====User Data====
# User Name：22
# User Name：22
# User Address：shanghai
tom = C('Tom', 22, 'shanghai')
tom.showInfo()
```

Comment: Both calls to `super().__init__()` are going to call the same base class, and the other base class doesn't get initialized at all.  Likewise, both calls to `super().showInfo()` call the same base class's implementation.  `super()` simply does not get along with the combination of multiple inheritance, and differing `__init__()` parameter lists (any two of those three things works just fine) - consider explicitly naming the base class you want to call in each place where you're currently using `super()`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```py
class A:
    def __init__(self, userName=''):
        self.userName = userName
    def showInfo(self):
        print(f'User Name：{self.userName}')


class B:
    def __init__(self, userAge=0):
        self.userAge = userAge
    def showInfo(self):
        print(f'User Age：{self.userAge}')


class C(A, B):
    def __init__(self, userName='', userAge=0, userAddress=''):
        A.__init__(self, userName)
        B.__init__(self, userAge)
        self.userAddress = userAddress

    def showInfo(self):
        print('====User Data====')
        A.showInfo(self)
        B.showInfo(self)
        print(f'User Address：{self.userAddress}')

tom = C('Tom', 22, 'shanghai')
tom.showInfo()
```

Comment: That's great, but I've searched a lot of articles on the web and they give a lot of information about super and MRO, it's puzzling! Your answer is great, I like the intuitive way 

Comment: By the way, I would like to ask, how will it be designed or solved if super is used here?

Comment: @chenqiandaxianren check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14206015/10237506). I couldn't get it to work with `super`, I think because it's not how it's to be used in this case.

Comment: Ok, I seem to know something, thank you ❤️