# Multiple inheritance super() initialization with different signatures

Tags: python

Let us suppose that we have two classes, one'c constructor takes  two arguments and second one take one argument, all of them have their own initialization. Now I want to create a third class which is derived from both of them and share their own initialization. Here is my attempt:

```
class SuperClass1:
    def __init__(self,x,y):
        self.x =x
        self.y =y


class SuperClass2:
    def __init__(self,z):
        self.z =z/2


class Derived(SuperClass1, SuperClass2):
    def __init__(self,x,y,z):
        super().__init__(x,y)
        super(SuperClass2).__init__(z)

d1 = Derived(10,11,12)
print(d1.x, d1.y, d1.z)
# d1 = Derived()
# d1.info()
```

but when I run, I get the following error:

```
TypeError: super() argument 1 must be type, not int
```

I am just learning myself and making experiments, please tell me if it possible to do this?

Edited :so you mean like this?

```
class Derived(SuperClass1, SuperClass2):
    def __init__(self,x,y,z):
        super().__init__(x,y)
        super(SuperClass1, self).__init__(z)
d1 =Derived(10,11,12)
print(d1.x,d1.y,d1.z)
```

Comment: You need to pass an object to which returned method will be bound - `super(SuperClass1, self).__init__(z)` (note the **1**)

Comment: (You'd need to do the same with first super, but `super()` is the same as `super(Derived, self)`)

Comment: but this line returns error : super(SuperClass1,self).__init__(x,y)

Comment: But that's not the line I wrote.

Comment: superclass1 does not have anything  with z

Comment: But it's before `SuperClass2` in MRO. Method Resolution Order is checked from the first class *after* specified. Since your MRO is `Derived -> SuperClass1 -> SuperClass2 -> object`, in order to get SuperClass2 you need to start searching after SuperClass1.

Comment: Yes, that's one way to do it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/257210/discussion-between-dato-and-matszwecja).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change Derived class like below:

```
class Derived(SuperClass1, SuperClass2):
    def __init__(self,x,y,z):
        SuperClass1.__init__(self,x,y)
        SuperClass2.__init__(self,z)
```

Reference here: [Python's Multiple Inheritance: Picking which super() to call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14206015/pythons-multiple-inheritance-picking-which-super-to-call)